# how to pre check column position before copy command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have 900+ columns coming in stage. I want to check position of columns should not change in inbound files before processing. What can be the best way to do this.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail such as file type, if delimited whether there's a header, etc.?

Comment: File type is CSV and the first record is header.. We are thinking to do minus query like select $1 minus select 'col1' ; But hardcoded string is not working beyond 10000 length.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake supports using standard SQL to query data files located in an internal (i.e. Snowflake) stage or named external (Amazon S3, Google Cloud Storage, or Microsoft Azure) stage. This can be useful for inspecting/viewing the contents of the staged files, particularly before loading or after unloading data.

Details & Syntax: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html#querying-data-in-staged-files